# uninitialized constant error using PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

In my rails app, I am trying to generate pdf from html and trying to use pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf. I am trying to start by simplest code like:

```
kit = PDFKit.new("<p>This is some text.</p>")
pdf = kit.to_file "/home/user/test.pdf"
```

But I am ending up with the following error:

```
uninitialized constant TestController::PDFKit
```

TestController is my controller name. FYI, I am using Fedora12 and rails 2.2.

Need some help. Anybody there?

Comment: How are you including the PDFKit ?  Is it via a require or gemfile ?

Comment: Its via require in environment.rb

Answer (score 5):

You add pdf mime type for your app:

open config/initializer/mime_types.rb , add this code :

> Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf

Hope it helps you.